# Как вывести таблицу из js в html?

Tags: javascript, html

Получаю с сервера информацию, заполняю массивы и пытаюсь вывести таблицу в html, но выдаёт ошибку"Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null". Перемещение скрипта в конец документа не помогает.

```
var html = '<table>';
for (i = 0; i < product.length; i++) {
  html += '<tr>';

  html += '<td>' + product[i] + '</td>';
  html += '<td>' + cost[i] + '</td>';
  html += '</tr>';
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = html;
};

<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: В Вашей странице нет элемента с `id="container"`.

Comment: есть, я забыл добавить 
<div class="container"></div>

Comment: @АртёмСимонов, в этом блоке есть `class`, но не `id`.

Comment: @АртёмСимонов Ну хорошо, есть - так есть. (Имеющий глаза - да увидит.)

Comment: **Почитайте справку:** [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Артём Симонов, если вас мой ответ удовлетворил, то поставьте галочку рядом с ответом слева, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('.container').innerHTML = html;
```

Не забудьте закрыть тэг `</table>`.

Answer (score 0):

Ваша ошибка заключалась в том, что вы ищете через `document.getElementById` по `id`, а в HTML у вас прописан `class`: `<div class="container"></div>`.

**Одно из решений:** `class` поменять на `id` в `HTML`: `<div id="container"></div>`.

Также у вас отсутствует закрывающий тэг `</table>` к таблице, но это не та причина, по которой ваш код не работает, ибо обозреватели сети подставляют сами закрывающие теги, если их нет. Но всё же так делать не стоит, т. к. может привести к ошибкам.

В общем, вот так работает:

```js
var product = ['Овёс', 'Пшеница', 'Кукуруза'];
var cost = [33, 35, 41];
var html = '<table border="1" cellpadding="3">';
for(var i = 0; i < product.length; i++)
{
 html += '<tr>';
 html += '<td>' + product[i] + '</td>';
 html += '<td>' + cost[i] + ' руб./кг.</td>';
 html += '</tr>';
}

window.onload = function()
{
 document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = html + '</table>';
};
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```